# A-Star Search with 3D Universe

Tags: python, python-2.x, graph, search, a-star

I am attempting to write up a program in Python that will find the shortest path between two nodes in 3D space. The actual domain is the EVE-Online Universe, which is composed of systems connected by stargates.

The input to my program is a list of systems, represented as Python dicts (JSON). I am trying to use the physical 3D distance as well as an incrementing step-cost as my two heuristics.

```
from math import sqrt
from Queue import PriorityQueue

class Universe(object):
    def __init__(self, systems):
        self._id_to_system = {system["system_id"]: system for system in systems}
        self._name_to_system = {system["name"]: system for system in systems}

    @property
    def num_systems(self):
        return len(self._id_to_system)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self._id_to_system:
            return self._id_to_system[key]
        elif key in self._name_to_system:
            return self._name_to_system[key]
        else:
            raise KeyError("No system with a name or id equal to {}".format(key))

def distance(a, b):
    """ Returns straight-line distance in AUs between two systems """
    a_pos = a["position"]
    b_pos = b["position"]

    x_dist = b_pos["x"] - a_pos["x"]
    y_dist = b_pos["y"] - b_pos["y"]
    z_dist = b_pos["z"] - b_pos["z"]

    distance = sqrt((x_dist)*(x_dist) + (y_dist)*(y_dist) + (z_dist)*(z_dist))
    # Convert from meters to AUs before returning - helps keep this number reasonable
    return distance / 1.496e+11


class SystemNode(object):
    """ Used to represent a system inside the open and closed sets """
    def __init__(self, system, parent, step_cost):
        self.system = system
        self.parent = parent
        self.step_cost = step_cost


def find_stargate_route(universe, start_system, end_system, step_cost=10):

    # Create open and closed sets
    frontier_nodes = PriorityQueue(universe.num_systems)
    closed_system_ids = {}

    # Add starting system to frontier
    start_node = SystemNode(start_system, None, 0)
    frontier_nodes.put((0, start_node))

    while not frontier_nodes.empty():
        # Grab the node with the lowest cost
        current_node = frontier_nodes.get(False)[1]

        # Check if we have found our goal
        if current_node.system == end_system:
            print("Found Route to {}".format(end_system["name"]))
            break

        # Calculate next node step cost
        next_step_cost = current_node.step_cost + step_cost

        # Add each output system if we haven't seen it yet
        for system_id in (
            stargate["destination"]["system_id"] for stargate in current_node.system["stargates"]
        ):
            system = universe[system_id]
            system_node = SystemNode(system, current_node, next_step_cost)

            # Check if system is in our closed list
            if system_id in closed_system_ids:
                continue

            # Add to our frontier with priority=step_cost + distance
            total_cost = distance(system, end_system) + next_step_cost
            frontier_nodes.put((total_cost, system_node))

        # Add the current node to the closed set            
        closed_system_ids[current_node.system["system_id"]] = current_node

    if current_node.system != end_system:
        return None
    else:
        # Return a list of systems from start to end
        route = []
        while current_node != None:
            route.insert(0, current_node.system)
            current_node = current_node.parent
        return route
```

And then a little program to run it...

A jsonl.gz file with all of the systems is available in [this gitlab snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1733170) (see the attached file - "combined_systems.jsonl.gz")

```
import gzip
import json

with gzip.open("combined_systems.jsonl.gz", 'rb') as gzfp:
    systems = [json.loads(line) for line in gzfp]


start_name = "Amarr"
end_name = "Jita"

universe = Universe(systems)

route = find_stargate_route(
    universe, universe[start_name], universe[end_name]
)

print(len(route))
```

Any suggestions? This was meant more as a coding exercise to help me grasp the A-star algorithm, so any pointers are much appreciated :)

**EDIT:** Removed the dependency on `PrioritySet` - it works the same with `Queue.PriorityQueue`. Also added my Universe class (basically just getters for the different systems). Also added a link to the `jsonl.gz` file containing all of the systems, see the gitlab link.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! For what Python version did you write this and does it work correctly?

Comment: To make it easier to reproduce, could you add your imports? Currently `PrioritySet` (and `Universe`) are undefined.

Comment: @Mast - It is in python2.7 and yes! It works correctly and finds routes, although I'm not too sure if they are the best routes out there

Comment: @Graipher - Added the `Universe` dependency, and removed my custom `PrioritySet` - it was basically just a PriorityQueue with some extra stuff thrown around. The above code should work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the `distance` function.

`distance = sqrt((x_dist)*(x_dist) + (y_dist)*(y_dist) + (z_dist)*(z_dist))` is how you would probably write it in C++, in Python there exists a more readable way using the `**` operator:

`distance = sqrt(x_dist**2 + y_dist**2 + z_dist**2)`

It is not even slower than doing the multiplication yourself:

```
In []: %timeit 123456789123456789123456789**2
12.4 ns ± 0.184 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)

In []: %timeit 123456789123456789123456789*123456789123456789123456789
12.5 ns ± 0.199 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```

You also have a **bug** in that function:

```
y_dist = b_pos["y"] - b_pos["y"]
z_dist = b_pos["z"] - b_pos["z"]
```

So your distance only takes into account the distance in x. In y and z it is always zero.

`1.496e+11` is a magic number. You should save it as a constant on the module level: `METER_PER_AU = 1.496e+11`.

---

In `find_stargate_route`, at the end when you have found the target system, you create the route to it. You do that using this code:

```
route = []
while current_node != None:
    route.insert(0, current_node.system)
    current_node = current_node.parent
return route
```

This has a bad runtime, because `list.insert` has a [worst case runtime](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) of \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$. Instead either use a data structure that supports appending on the left (like `collections.deque`), or just build the path using `list.append` and return `list(reversed(route))` at the end.

[You should also not compare to `None` using `==` or `!=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or), instead use `is` and `is not`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - can't believe I missed the distance function calculations (it explains why I was getting a sub-optimal route).